# Using environment variables instead of reverse.dep to make builds "suitable"

Tags: teamcity

**Context:**

We're running the free version of Teamcity to manage our projects. Some of those projects have dependencies between each others.

**The problem**

Some projects have chained Snapshot Dependencies, and those dependencies are always being built instead of the latest artifacts from those dependencies being used.

Example: A depends on B, B depends on C. Push A triggers a build of C, followed by a build of B and finally a build of A.

Ideally: A would be built based on the latest built versions of B and C

**Where I think the problem lies (but I might be wrong)**

Each of our projects has a number of Snapshot dependencies, and each snapshot dependency is configured with the following parameters turned on:

- [x] Do not run new build if there is a suitable one
- [x] Only use successful builds from suitable ones

For the first option, the documentation says:

> If this option is set, TeamCity will not run a new dependency build, if another dependency build in progress or completed with the appropriate source revision already exists. See also Suitable builds: (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2022.10/snapshot-dependencies.html#Suitable+Builds).

If we look in the Suitable Builds doc, it shows a list of requirements for a build to be considered suitable. The one I think is relevant is here:

- It must not have any custom settings, including those defined via reverse.dep. (related feature request: TW-23700: (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23700)).

However, we currently have `reverse.dep.*.env.SOME_PARAMETER` as a Configuration Parameter in every single one of our builds (it's inherited through a template).

Based on that, it seems to me that the "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" option is doing nothing, and therefore that's why all our dependencies are built every time (or am I wrong?)

We also have, in every one of our builds, an environment variable called `env.SOME_PARAMETER` which has the same value as the reverse.dep configuration parameter.

**My question**

Is there a way to avoid using `reverse.dep` in my situation so that the `Do not run new build if there is a suitable one` option works? Perhaps by using the environment variable instead?

I asked the senior developer at the company I work in, and they said that in theory it should work, but in practice it doesn't, but he seems recitent to explain further. I'm just a beginner in Teamcity, so detailed explanations are welcome

Answer (score -1):

### First things first: what is a Snapshot Dependency in a nutshell?

A Snapshot Dependency in a nutshell is a dependency between two build configurations which are linked by shared VCS Roots. VCS Roots are sort of like time lines in a book: they represent a chain of events (e.g. git commit history) and let you build from a givent point in time (e.g. commit).

Now, TeamCity excels at doing what it is intended to do: Continuous Integration and Deployment. It does so by being tied up closely to VCS Roots and effectively changes in these (optionally narrowed down scopes of the) VCS roots. A Snapshot Dependency is a dependency which links together the dependency based on VCS Roots and their changes.

### An example

Build A has two VCS Roots, Foo and Bar. Foo and Bar are, say, different Git repositories which Build A needs to fetch before it is able to build the "A" artifact. Build B only needs Foo, and thus only has Foo attached as a VCS Root. Build A has a Snapshot Dependency on Build B, which we configure like yours: `"Do not run new build if there is a suitable one"` and `"Only use successful builds from suitable ones"`.

So far so good. Now let's push a new commit to the "Foo" repository. TeamCity notices this and potentially triggers a new build of Build A, because the latest build of A is at that point outdated (it did not have our latest Foo commit included). The Snapshot Dependency of B in A links these two build configurations together so that - with our above configuration of the Dep. - we can require a build of B which includes the same revision of Foo, that build A was kicked off with (e.g. the latest commit). Because this does not (yet) exist, a build of B is started and put above build A in the queue.

Simply put: the VCS Root is a timeline, the Snapshot Dependency is a link between two build configurations based on the timeline(s) they have in common, and the configuration of the dependency dictates what should happen when a dependency is needed (e.g. "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one").

If we had manually started a build B with the latest Foo revision included, this would have been a suitable candidate for reuse, and TeamCity would simply remove the queued B build once it discovered that a build of B already exists, which shares the same changes that build A is started with (the latest push to Foo).

### If you want just the latest artifacts of B and C...

...use Artifact Dependencies and only these. Removing the Snapshot Dependency of the build removes your need of having the dependency build every time Build A is triggered by a new change in its VCS Root. It however also means that there is no timeline linkage between the two builds and that you yourself need to ensure or be sure that the artifacts produced by B and C are not tightly linked to A. E.g. Build C could produce a driver as an artifact, B could produce a user manual of the driver and build A could just be using the driver, only expecting that it is in a working condition (but otherwise does not depend on changes in it).

### Your question about reverse.dep.*...

I've not heard about this causing trouble before. I would however expect that a Snapshot Dependency (and not just an artifact dependency) is required by TeamCity for you to be allowed to use it.

Question is: do you *need it?* It sounds like you've got the value elsewhere already, and honestly fetching values from previous builds is likely going to cause you trouble in the long run, especially if you don't have a specifically good reason to do so.